# Kivy Python - Callback Function with partial

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I want to 'pull' some values from my Arduino in kivy on Raspberry, which is connected via a wireless NRF24 module. I am using [this](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/) library with a [python wrapper](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/Python.html)

In pure Python the code works well and now I want to integrate it in Kivy.

For that I made two functions inside `zimmerwetter.py`:

One for setting up the radio device and returns the radio object (should be running once the application starts):

```
def radiosetup():
    radio = RF24(RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_22, RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_24, BCM2835_SPI_SPEED_8MHZ)

    # doing setup stuff...

    return radio
```

and another function which send an request to the Arduino which delivers some enviroment date (temperatur, humidity etc.).

```
def getenviroment(self,radio):

    millis = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    # send command
    send_payload = 'getdata'
    # First, stop listening so we can talk.

    radio.stopListening()

    # Take the time, and send it.  This will block until complete
    print 'Now sending length ', len(send_payload), ' ... ',
    radio.write(send_payload[:len(send_payload)])

    a = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Now, continue listening
    radio.startListening()

    # Wait here until we get a response, or timeout
    started_waiting_at = millis()
    timeout = False
    while (not radio.available()) and (not timeout):
        if (millis() - started_waiting_at) > 1000:
            timeout = True

    # Describe the results
    if timeout:
        b = datetime.datetime.now()
        #      print(b - a)
        print 'failed, response timed out.'
    else:
        # Grab the response, compare, and send to debugging spew
        length = radio.getDynamicPayloadSize()
        receive_payload = []
        receive_payload = radio.read(length)

        print 'got response size=', length
        print struct.unpack("bbbbhbbbb", ''.join(chr(c) for c in receive_payload))
        b = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(b - a)
        return receive_payload
```

The getenviroment function should be called later every x seconds from the kivy app, the partial function is used as suggested in [the kivy clock module](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/clock.py)

```
from zimmerwetter import *

class PyowmApp(App):
    def build(self):
        radio = radiosetup()
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(getenviroment,radio), 10)
```

The Error is :

```
   File "/home/pi/pyscripts/pyowm/zimmerwetter.py", line 83, in getenviroment
     radio.stopListening()
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'stopListening'
```

I am wondering why a float object is returned, when I print the radio object with help(radio), it returns `class RF24(Boost.Python.instance)` and the function stoplistening() exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function called by `Clock.schedule_interval` will receive `dt` as an argument after the ones passed through `partial`. The signature for your function is `getenviroment(self,radio)`, so `radio` will be assigned to `self` and `dt` will be assigned to `radio`.

Instead, use `lambda`:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.getenviroment(radio), 10)
```

Comment: changing the statement to  `Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: getenviroment(radio), 10)` and removing the self argument from the functon is working too (the function ist not declared in the scope of the App)

Comment: @Triscus the question doesn't state where `getenviroment` is defined, so I assumed `PyownApp`. Replace `self` with the correct instance of the class that has `getenvironment`. Or consider changing the parameter `self`.

Comment: The functions were not defined within a class, only with a `def` Statement. Guess I should get used to OOP, thank you for your inspiration

Comment: @Triscus that is perfectly fine, but in that case the first argument to `getenvironment` shouldn't be `self` ...

Answer (score 0):

I've found it out by myself, changing the schedule statement to

```
Clock.schedule_interval(partial(getenviroment,radio=radio), 10)
```

did the trick.

Comment: This works, but it's not very clear: What happens here is that through `partial` the positional argument passed by `schedule_interval` (`dt`) gets assigned to the first argument in `getenvironment` (`self`). `self` is not used later on, so there's no issue. Then, `radio` gets assigned by name, with the expected value. So if `self` actually had some meaning, this approach would not work and produce unexpected results/errors. Just thought I point it out …